# StringIO current stream position after object creation seems to be wrong?

Tags: python

I am struggling with the current stream position of StringIO objects. I create a StringIO object with initial content. Then when adding strings with `write()` the content gets overwritten.

```py
f = io.StringIO("some initial text data")

f.write(' and some strings and other stuff')

print(f.getvalue())
```

yields to

```py
 and some strings and other stuff
```

Checking the current stream position after object creation:

```py
f = io.StringIO("some initial text data")
f.tell()
```

gives

```
0
```

That's pretty confusing. I expected the stream position at the end of 'some initial text data'.
I can calculate the length of the initial string and then set the position manually with `f.seek(initial_string_length)`
But this seems cumbersome.

Are there any other ideas?
And is this the intended behaviour of StringIO objects?

Comment: Use `f.seek(0, 2)` to seek relative to the end of the file.  This *is* documented behavior: "The stream is positioned at the start of the buffer." (which is exactly what you'd want if you're going to read from the StringIO object).

Comment: `The stream is positioned at the start of the buffer.`  from here:   https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```
The stream is positioned at the start of the buffer
```

`f.seek(0, 2)` did the trick. Or better `f.seek(0, SEEK_END)`